# If $F(x,y)$ is a polynomial which is not a square, then how often is the specialization $F(x,a)$ a square?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

Suppose $F(x,y)$ is a polynomial in two variables over a field $K$, and $F(x,y)$ is not a square. When is $F(x,a)$ a square for $a\in K$? I would guess that Hilbert's Irreducibility Theorem might help (if $K$ is hilbertian), but I am not sure how.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. When $K$ is the complex numbers, $x^2y$ isn't a square, but $ax^2$ is for all $a$.

Comment: If K is Hilbertian then Hilbert's Irreducibility Theorem applies to $z^2-F(x,y)$

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, the question is a bit open to interpretation, but I am just hoping to understand what, for instance sets $x^2y$ (for which each specialization gives a square) apart from $x^2+y$ for which almost no specialization gives a square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $F(x,y)=G(x,y)^2H(x,y)$ with polynomials $G,H$, such that $H(x,y)$, considered as a polynomial in $x$ over $K(y)$, is squarefree. If $H(x,y)$ does not involve $x$, so $H(x,y)=h(y)$, then you are reduced to an arithmetical question depending on $K$. For instance if $K$ is Hilbertian, and $h(y)$ is a not a square, then $h(a)$ is not a square infinitely often.

If however $H(x,y)$ involves $x$, then $H(x,y)$ and its derivative $H'(x,y)=\frac{\partial H(x,y)}{\partial x}$ with respect to $x$ are relatively prime, provided that $H'(x,y)\ne0$. The Bezout Lemma then yields polynomials $A(x,y)$, $B(x,y)$ and a nonzero polynomial $c(y)$ such that $A(x,y)H(x,y)+B(x,y)H'(x,y)=c(y)$. So whenever $c(a)\ne0$, then $H(x,a)$ is still separable, so in particular it is not a square.

*Remark:* As pointed out by Will Sawin, the argument needs to be enhanced if $K$ has positive characteristic. Since I don't know whether the OP is interested in that too, and because the treatment becomes somewhat more technical, I'll leave that case open.

Comment: You are implicitly assuming that if $H(x,y)$ is squarefree in $K[x,y]$ then it is squarefree in $\overline{K(y)}[x]$. This is true in characteristic zero, but false in characteristic $p$. I think the main claim is true in all odd characteritstics, but $x^2-y$ is a counterexample in characteristic $2$.

Comment: @WillSawin: Thanks, I added a remark.